# Getting specific table from web page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I want to get the data from the 3rd table on http://www.dividend.com/dividend-stocks/.
Here is the code and I need some help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.dividend.com/dividend-stocks/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html5lib")

# Skip first two tables
tables = soup.find("table")
tables = tables.find_next("table")
tables = tables.find_next("table")

row = ''
for td in tables.find_all("td"):
    if len(td.text.strip()) > 0:
        row = row + td.text.strip().replace('\n', ' ') +','
        # Handle last column in a row, remove extra comma and add new line
        if td.get('data-th') == 'Pay Date':
            row = row[:-1] + '\n'
print(row)
```

1. Is there a better way to skip the two tables? Or is there a simple way to skip a big block of code in beautiful soup? If so, how can I position it?
2. Somehow the output order of the code is different from the ones on the web. The table on the web looks like this: [image]

but code output is like this:

```
AAPL,Apple Inc.,1.76%,$143.39,$2.52,5/11,5/18
GE,General Electric,3.32%,$28.91,$0.96,6/15,7/25
XOM,Exxon Mobil,3.71%,$83.03,$3.08,5/10,6/9
CVX,Chevron Corp,4.01%,$107.72,$4.32,5/17,6/12
BP,BP PLC ADR,6.66%,$35.72,$2.38,5/10,6/23
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please give your question a title that describes it more specifically. Most questions here are about code that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for pointing out. I will be more careful next time.

Comment: @fuzzyworm It looks like you are saving them in a CSV-like format but there are 3 companies with commas in the names so you might want to put the company names inside of double-quotes. `Qualcomm, Inc`, `Banco Santander, S.A.`, `Activision Blizzard, Inc.`

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce You are right. I will fix that part. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a selector to find a specific table:

```
tables = soup.select("table:nth-of-type(3)")
```

I'm not sure why your results are in a different order than they appear on the web page.

Answer (score 1):

Although [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) 's method seems cleaner, here is another alternative using `soup.find_all` and saving to JSON (even though that wasn't in the description).

```
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.dividend.com/dividend-stocks/'
r = requests.get(url)
r.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
stocks = {}

# Skip first two tables and header row of target table
for tr in soup.find_all('table')[2].find_all('tr')[1:]:
    (stock_symbol, company_name, _, dividend_yield, current_price,
     annual_dividend, ex_dividend_date, pay_date) = [
        td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')]
    stocks[stock_symbol] = {
        'company_name': company_name,
        'dividend_yield': float(dividend_yield.rstrip('%')),
        'current_price': float(current_price.lstrip('$')),
        'annual_dividend': float(annual_dividend.lstrip('$')),
        'ex_dividend_date': ex_dividend_date,
        'pay_date': pay_date
    }

with open('stocks.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(stocks, f, indent=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for doing the code. It is always nice to have a different way to solve a problem. I can't get it to work on my windows machine yet. Need a bit research. Will ask for help if I can't figure out. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. I did use 'lxml' as the HTML parser (since I already had it installed). If that is the issue, you could try installing it or changing it back to the HTML parser you used originally.

Comment: Yes, with a different parser, everything is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Barmar and @Delirious Lettuce for posting the solution and codes. 
Regarding the order of the output, I realized every time I refresh the data, I saw a glimpse of the data in the order of the output like I pulled. Then I see the sorted data. Tried a few different ways, I was able to use the Selenium webdriver to pull the data like the web presented. Thanks all.

```
BPT,BP Prudhoe Bay Royalty Trust,21.12%,$20.80,$4.39,4/11,4/20
PER,Sandridge Permian Trust,18.06%,$2.88,$0.52,5/10,5/26
CHKR,Chesapeake Granite Wash Trust,16.75%,$2.40,$0.40,5/18,6/1
NAT,Nordic American Tankers,13.33%,$6.00,$0.80,5/18,6/8
WIN,Windstream Corp,13.22%,$4.54,$0.60,6/28,7/17
NYMT,New York Mortgage Trust Inc,12.14%,$6.59,$0.80,6/22,7/25
IEP,Icahn Enterprises L.P.,11.65%,$51.50,$6.00,5/11,6/14
FTR,Frontier Communications,11.51%,$1.39,$0.16,6/13,6/30
```